# Why does the ordering of optional args appear to make this rsync statement fail?

Tags: linux, path, backup, rsync, optional-parameters

This rsync command is failing for reasons that appear to be inexplicable, because each constituent part works when you break it down. And when you put it back together, the whole thing works after all. The only apparent difference being the ordering of the optional parameter args.

The problem is that it copies files not from the given source path but from the present working directory. Yet it sill interprets the destintation path correctly.

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    --exclude='**/.local/share/Trash/**' \
    --exclude='lost+found'            \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
    --delete \
    "$dryrun" \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

All of these following commands work as expected, copying files from the given source path to the given destination.

**1.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

**2.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

**3.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

It seems the problem is with these exclude statements then:

```
    --exclude='**/.local/share/Trash/**' \
    --exclude='lost+found'            \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
```

Yet they all work when you break them down:

**4.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

**5.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
    --exclude='lost+found'            \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

Finally, the whole command again - precisely the same, as the faulty original, with the exception that the optional args are in a different order:

**6.**

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --delete \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
    --exclude='lost+found'            \
    --exclude='**/.local/share/Trash/**' \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

All of the test commands are precisely the same in their parts because I formulated each by copying it from the original command. All of the variables and paths are valid.

So the command seems to work when reassembled. Perhaps there is some minor difference I made along the way? No. If I issue the precise original command again, it still fails:

```
rsync \
\
    -uaXzxvhhh \
    --log-file="$logfp" \
    --info=NAME,PROGRESS2,REMOVE,DEL,COPY,BACKUP,STATS2 \
    --exclude='**/.local/share/Trash/**' \
    --exclude='lost+found'            \
    --exclude='*.iso'                 \
    --delete \
    "$dryrun" \
    "$source_path" "$destination_path"
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: If option `"$dryrun" ` is a zero-length string, I'm not sure what rsync does with it.

Comment: None of the versions that work include `"$dryrun"`, so I think that's the problem.